# Is this the right way to get content assist for javascript files in Eclipse Helios (Java EE)?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.6, helios

I have a Java EE project which contains some JavaScript files. I followed the below option to get content assist for Javascript files.

**Right click the project -> Configure -> Convert to JavaScript Project**

*(only .project and .settings folder of the project got modified)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the content assist is already builtin and is triggered on files with `.js` extension. To do a quick test, enter `for` and then `Ctrl+Space`, you should get a choice list with various loop templates. Configuration can be done by *Window > Preferences > JavaScript*.

The default JavaScript content assist is however pretty limited in capabilities as opposed to the Java content assist in `.java` files. If you want better content assist for JS (and HTML/CSS/XML files), consider installing the [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) plugin.